# Stopped JS execution while opening a file?

Tags: javascript, windows, browser

I'm having a very weird JS issue here: JS doesn't seem to run at all while the user selects a file for upload. To cause it simply don't close the file selection dialog. After a while the session times out. I've tried all sorts of settings, but I can't get around it.

I'm not sure, but it looks like it's only IE. Chrome and FF seem to run JS in the background.

Is there something I can include into the web page to tell the browser not to halt JS while picking files ?

Comment: Just an idea, have you tried web workers (separate thread)?

Comment: A colleague did just that. That did it. :-)

Comment: Great, I'm glad you could make it work. That's what's great about web workers. They are not affected by the user interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution as proposed by @blex works perfectly.